# Convert HTML table data in form of array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue the array is showing undefined even if i am storing the table data into an array
https://leetcode.com/tag/array/

Getting every problem's row in the form of an array

```
function getAllProblemRowElements() {
    //var k = document.querySelector("#app > div > div > div > div.table-responsive > table > tbody");
    const tableContents = document.querySelector("#app > div > div > div > div.table-responsive > table > tbody");
    const sources = Array.from(tableContents,source=>tableContents[0]);
    return sources;

}
```

Please resolve it

Comment: Which test is it?

Answer (score 1):

Table content to Array

```js
var myTableData = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr'), function(row){
  return Array.prototype.map.call(row.querySelectorAll('td'), function(td){
    return td.innerHTML;
    });
  });

console.log(myTableData)
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ES6 version

```js
const myTableData = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr')]
  .map(row => [...row.querySelectorAll('td')]
    .map(cell => cell.textContent));

console.log(myTableData)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem row defined in your question is the title. You can use the `querySelectorAll` in `document` to get all the rows and then map it into an array. Hope the below code helps:

```js
function getAllProblemRowElements() {

    const tableContents = document.querySelectorAll("#app > div > div > div > div.table-responsive > table > tbody > tr");
    const sources = Array.from(tableContents,source=>source.children[2].getAttribute("value"))
    return sources;
}
```

Comment: This is assuming input fields - did you identify the actual problem at leetcode?